# Python:ValueError: shapes (3,) and (118,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 118 (dim 0)

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I am trying to do logistic regression using fmin but there is an error showing up due to different shapes of array. Here is the code.

```
import numpy as np

import scipy.optimize as sp

data= #an array of dim (188,3)

X=data[:,0:2]
y=data[:,2]
m,n=np.shape(X)
y=y.reshape(m,1)
x=np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),X]
theta=np.zeros((n+1,1))


def hypo(x,theta): 
    return np.dot(x,theta)

def sigmoid(z):
    return 1/(1+np.exp(-z))
    
def gradient(x,y,theta):#calculating Gradient
    m=np.shape(x)[0]
    t=hypo(x,theta)
    hx=sigmoid(t)
    J=-(np.dot(np.transpose(np.log(hx)),y)+np.dot(np.transpose(np.log(1-hx)),(1-y)))/m
    grad=np.dot(np.transpose(x),(hx-y))/m
    J= J.flatten()
    grad=grad.flatten()
    return J,grad
    
def costFunc(x,y,theta):    
    return gradient(x,y,theta)[0]
    
def Grad():
   return gradient(x,y,theta)[1]

sp.fmin( costFunc, x0=theta, args=(x, y), maxiter=500, full_output=True)
```

## error that is showing

```
File "<ipython-input-3-31a0d7ca38c8>", line 35, in costFunc

return gradient(x,y,theta)[0]

File "<ipython-input-3-31a0d7ca38c8>", line 25, in gradient

t=hypo(x,theta)

File "<ipython-input-3-31a0d7ca38c8>", line 16, in hypo

return np.dot(x,theta)

ValueError: shapes (3,) and (118,1) not aligned: 3 (dim 0) != 118 (dim 0)
```

Any kind of help will be appreciated

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
data= #an array of dim (188,3)

X=data[:,0:2]
y=data[:,2]
m,n=np.shape(X)
y=y.reshape(m,1)
x=np.c_[np.ones((m,1)),X]
theta=np.zeros((n+1,1))
```

so after this

```
In [14]: y.shape
Out[14]: (188, 1)   # is this (118,1)?
In [15]: x.shape
Out[15]: (188, 3)
In [16]: theta.shape
Out[16]: (3, 1)
```

This `x` and `theta` can `dotted` - `np.dot(x,theta)`, and (188,3) with (3,1) - matching the 3's.

But that's not what your `costFunc` is getting.  Tracing back from the error message it looks like `x` is `(3,)`, and `theta` is `(118,1)`. which obviously cannot be `dotted`.

You need to review how `fmin` calls your function.  Do you have the parameters in the right order?  For example, maybe `costFunc(theta, x, y)` is the correct order (assuming the `x` and `y` in `costFunc` are meant to match with the `args=(x,y)`.

The docs for `fmin` include:

> ```
> func : callable func(x,*args)
>     The objective function to be minimized.
> x0 : ndarray
>     Initial guess.
> args : tuple, optional
>     Extra arguments passed to func, i.e. ``f(x,*args)``.
> ```

It looks like `fmin` is feeding your `costFunc` 3 arguments, corresponding in size to your `(theta, x, y)`, i.e. `(3,)`, `(118,3)`, `(118,1)`.  The numbers don't quite match, but I think you get the idea.  The first argument to `consFunc` is the one that the `fmin` will vary, the rest you provide in `args`.

Comment: Thanks man I just had to change in position of parameters in functions and sub-functions called by fmin.